# Reload a bean configuration xml file in a spring boot application without restarting

Tags: xml, spring, spring-boot, configuration, reload

The Application class.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ServerBApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(ServerBApplication.class, args);
}

private Student stu;

public ServerBApplication() {
    FileSystemXmlApplicationContext cont = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("./config/student.xml");
    stu = cont.getBean(Student.class);
    cont.close();
    cont.destroy();
}

@Bean
Student stu() {
    return stu;
}
}
```

And the xml file

```
<bean id="stu" name="stu" class="com.example.demo.Student">
    <property name="id" value="100"></property>
    <property name="name" value="summer"></property>
</bean>
```

Reload controller.

```
@RestController
public class ReloadController {

@Autowired
Student stu;

@RequestMapping(value = "/reload", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String reload() {
    FileSystemXmlApplicationContext cont = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("./config/student.xml");
    stu = cont.getBean(Student.class);
    cont.close();
    cont.destroy();
    return "Reload success." + stu.toSting();
}
}
```

I want change some value/propery of **./config/student.xml** then run method **/reload**,but i still get student value with

> id:100,name:summer

Counld someone tell me It's possible to change the **stu**'s value/propery when I run **/reload** method without restarting application.Thanks a lot.

Comment: What you want called Spring Cloud `@RequestScope` . The first task, you must add Spring Cloud dependencies to your class-path. You can see [**authoritative example**](https://spring.io/guides/gs/centralized-configuration/) . When use this technique? When you want dynamic configuration for your cloud application. For trivial purpose, you use Spring Boot [**devtools**](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html) for development process.

Comment: Request Scope is not part of Spring Cloud, its bound to Web requests. https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/annotation/RequestScope.html You don't need Spring Cloud Config for this example, as you could bind that bean to RequestScoping. However, reloading configurations is difficult as dependencies that are created (can) be inject into singleton objects which cloud config helps with but you need to design your boot applications differently.

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.test;

import org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory;
import org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.DisposableBean;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Proxy;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock;


public class RefreshableSqlSessionFactoryBean extends SqlSessionFactoryBean implements DisposableBean {
  private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RefreshableSqlSessionFactoryBean.class);
  private SqlSessionFactory proxy;
  private int interval = 500;
  private Timer timer;
  private TimerTask task;
  private Resource[] refreshableMapperLocations;
  private boolean running = false;
  private final ReentrantReadWriteLock rwl = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
  private final Lock r = rwl.readLock();
  private final Lock w = rwl.writeLock();

  public RefreshableSqlSessionFactoryBean() {
    
  }

  @Override
  public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
    super.afterPropertiesSet();
    setRefreshable();
  }

  public void setRefreshableMapperLocations(Resource[] refreshableMapperLocations) {
    this.refreshableMapperLocations = refreshableMapperLocations;
  }

  public void setInterval(int ms) {
    this.interval = ms;
  }

  public void setCheckInterval(int ms) {
    interval = ms;
    if (timer != null) {
      resetInterval();
    }
  }

  private void refresh() throws Exception {
    if (logger.isInfoEnabled()) {
      logger.info("> Refresh SqlMapper...");
    }
    w.lock();
    try {
      super.afterPropertiesSet();
      logger.info("> Done.");
      logger.info("======================================================================================");
    } finally {
      w.unlock();
    }
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("java:S3776")
  private void setRefreshable() {
    proxy = (SqlSessionFactory) Proxy.newProxyInstance(SqlSessionFactory.class.getClassLoader(),
                                                       new Class[]{SqlSessionFactory.class},
                                                       (aProxy, method, args) -> method.invoke(getParentObject(),
                                                                                               args));

    task = new TimerTask() {
      private final Map<Resource, Long> map = new HashMap<>();

      @Override
      public void run() {
        if (isModified()) {
          try {
            refresh();
          } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("caught exception", e);
          }
        }
      }

      private boolean isModified() {
        if (refreshableMapperLocations != null) {
          List<String> modifiedResources = new ArrayList<>();
          for (Resource mappingLocation : refreshableMapperLocations) {
            modifiedResources.addAll(findModifiedResource(mappingLocation));
          }
          if (!modifiedResources.isEmpty()) {
            if(logger.isInfoEnabled()) {
              logger.info("======================================================================================");
              logger.info("> Update File name : {}", modifiedResources);
            }
            return true;
          }
        }
        return false;
      }

      private List<String> findModifiedResource(Resource resource) {
        List<String> modifiedResources = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
          long modified = resource.lastModified();
          if (map.containsKey(resource)) {
            long lastModified = map.get(resource);
            if (lastModified != modified) {
              map.put(resource, modified);
              //modifiedResources.add(resource.getDescription()); // 전체경로
              modifiedResources.add(resource.getFilename()); // 파일명
            }
          } else {
            map.put(resource, modified);
          }
        } catch (IOException e) {
          logger.error("caught exception", e);
        }

        return modifiedResources;
      }
    };

    timer = new Timer(true);
    resetInterval();
  }

  private SqlSessionFactory getParentObject() throws Exception {
    r.lock();
    try {
      return super.getObject();
    } finally {
      r.unlock();
    }
  }

  private void resetInterval() {
    if (running) {
      timer.cancel();
      running = false;
    }
    if (interval > 0) {
      timer.schedule(task, 0, interval);
      running = true;
    }
  }

  @Override
  public SqlSessionFactory getObject() {
    try {
      getParentObject();  // build factory if necessary
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return this.proxy;
  }

  @Override
  public Class<? extends SqlSessionFactory> getObjectType() {
    return (this.proxy != null ? this.proxy.getClass() : SqlSessionFactory.class);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isSingleton() {
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public void destroy() {
    timer.cancel();
  }
}
```

```
package com.test;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils;
import org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory;
import org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.io.IOException;


public class NodeConfigurationHelper {
  private NodeConfigurationHelper() {
  }

  static SqlSessionFactory createRefreshableSqlSessionFactory(ApplicationContext applicationContext,
                                                              DataSource dataSource) throws IOException {
    RefreshableSqlSessionFactoryBean sqlSessionFactoryBean = new RefreshableSqlSessionFactoryBean();
    setSqlSessionFactoryBeanCommonSettings(sqlSessionFactoryBean, applicationContext, dataSource);

    // for refresh query
    sqlSessionFactoryBean.setInterval(1000);
    Resource[] mapper1 = applicationContext.getResources("classpath:/mapper/tibero/**/*.xml");
    Resource[] mapper2 = applicationContext.getResources("classpath:/com/daou/sabangnet/dao/**/*.xml");
    Resource[] mappers = ArrayUtils.addAll(mapper1, mapper2);
    sqlSessionFactoryBean.setRefreshableMapperLocations(mappers);

    return sqlSessionFactoryBean.getObject();
  }

  static void setSqlSessionFactoryBeanCommonSettings(SqlSessionFactoryBean sqlSessionFactoryBean,
                                                     ApplicationContext applicationContext,
                                                     DataSource dataSource) throws IOException {
    sqlSessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);

    sqlSessionFactoryBean.setConfigLocation(applicationContext.getResource("classpath:/mapper/mybatis-config.xml"));
    sqlSessionFactoryBean.setMapperLocations(applicationContext.getResources("classpath:/mapper/tibero/*.xml"));
  }
}
```

```
package com.test;

import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig;
import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory;
import org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean;
import org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.io.IOException;

@Slf4j
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:/application.properties")
public class Node01DatabaseConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.node01.connection-pool-size}")
    private Integer maxConnectionPool;

    @Bean(name="node01Configuration")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.datasource.node01")
    public HikariConfig node01Config() {
        HikariConfig hikariConfig = new HikariConfig();
        hikariConfig.setMaximumPoolSize(maxConnectionPool);
        return hikariConfig;
    }

    @Bean(name="node01DataSource")
    public DataSource node01DataSource() {
        HikariConfig firstConfig = node01Config();
        log.info("Max. Hikari Connections for Node01 DB: {}", firstConfig.getMaximumPoolSize());
        DataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource(node01Config());
        log.info("datasource : {}", dataSource);
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean(name="node01SessionFactory")
    @Profile("local")
    public SqlSessionFactory refreshableSqlSessionFactory(@Qualifier("node01DataSource") DataSource dataSource)
            throws IOException {
        return NodeConfigurationHelper.createRefreshableSqlSessionFactory(applicationContext, dataSource);
    }

    @Bean(name="node01SessionFactory")
    @Profile("!local")
    public SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory(@Qualifier("node01DataSource") DataSource dataSource) throws Exception {
        SqlSessionFactoryBean sqlSessionFactoryBean = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
        NodeConfigurationHelper.setSqlSessionFactoryBeanCommonSettings(sqlSessionFactoryBean, applicationContext, dataSource);

        return sqlSessionFactoryBean.getObject();
    }

    @Bean(name="01TrManager")
    public DataSourceTransactionManager returnTransactionManager(@Qualifier("node01DataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean(name="node01SessionTemplate")
    public SqlSessionTemplate sqlSessionTemplate(@Qualifier("node01SessionFactory") SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory) {
        return new SqlSessionTemplate(sqlSessionFactory);
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).